# Grep qstat with a variable returns nothing

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, sh

I am having trouble greping qstat with a variable

**Scenario**: script-A my wrapper submits another script-B as a job, inside script-B I am submitting other jobs in a loop(job1,job2..jobx), each of these jobs have different job-names which are stored in a variable $New_OS. I am trying to make my script-B sleep until all (Job1,job2..jobx) are completed.

**Script**:

```
Job_status=`qstat | grep "${New_OS}" | wc -l`
echo -e "\n\nJob_status: $Job_status"
while [ $Job_status -ne "0" ];
do
    echo -e "Running PostProcessing for $Job_status sampleR, sleeping for 3 minutes..."
    sleep 3m
    Job_status=`qstat | grep "${New_OS}" | wc -l`
done;
```

**Problem**: The variable $Job_status which is supposed to return the number of jobs with a name $New_OS only returns 0 even though the jobs are still running.

**Question**: Why the grep of $New_OS in qstat is not returning the jobs with $New_OS as their names? I couldn't figure out the problem here, please suggest me a solution or a work around. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please format your answer to make it clearer

Comment: @Liam Healy Is it clear now? Please let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally adding '*' in my grep worked.

```
   Job_status1=`qstat | grep ${New_OS}* | wc -l`
```

Expected grep to work without that '*', since I am not looking to 'grep -w' for an exact match. I am sharing it just in case if someone ends up in a similar situation. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly try once my solution too and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using following.

```
Job_status1=$(qstat | grep -c ${New_OS}*)
```

Since I don't have `qstat` in my system so couldn't check, it should work but, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Ravinder,
Can you please share the diagnosis or a brief detail how your solution would work?